# Не могу сделать так что бы голова персонажа поворачивалась за курсором в Godot GDScript

Tags: godot, gdscript

Я сделал игру, потом захотел что бы голова персонажа следила за мышкой, я обыскал все видео, форумы, и т.д., и так не нашёл как это сделать, потому что не работает...

Код для головы:

```
extends Sprite
func _process(delta):
    
    var Golova = $Golova
    
    var rotation = get_global_mouse_position()

    if rotation > 0:
        $Golova.flip_h = false  
    else:
        $Golova.flip_h = true
```

В итоге она просто смотрит в одну точку. Помогите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо.

Comment: какое значение возвращает `get_global_mouse_position`

Comment: Извините, я ещё новичок, а как узнать?

Comment: А так нельзя? `look_at(get_global_mouse_position())`

Comment: https://ask.godotengine.org/78421/how-to-make-the-object-rotate-towards-the-mouse

Comment: можно например просто вывести значение rotation и посмотреть

Answer (score 0):

```
extends Node2D # "extends Sprite" в Вашем коде

@onready var head = $BasicFurniture # "var Golova = $Golova" в Вашем коде, я перенес её из функции, вместо "$BasicFurniture" Пишете нужный объект

func _process(delta):
    # Убрал "var rotation = get_global_mouse_position()", использую её напрямую, в условии:

    if head.position < get_global_mouse_position(): # Ваше условие
        head.flip_h = true # Тут меняете значение, если смотрит в обратную сторону от мыши
    else:
        head.flip_h = false # На другое соответственно
```

Всё делалось на Godot 4.0, отличие от Godot 3.5 только в строке `@onready var head = $BasicFurniture`, в старых версиях писалось без `@`

> E 0:00:00.927 get_node: (Node not found: "Golova"

Ваша ошибка указывает на ненахождение ноды `$Golova`. Если несколько причин для этого:

1. `$Golova` - это нода, к которой прикреплен ваш скрипт, советую прикреплять скрипт к главной ноде (на изображении `Main`), либо обращаться к этой ноде через `self` (`self.posiotion` или просто `position`)
2. Неправильный путь к ноде (На изображении есть две разных ноды с одинаковым именем, если вызывать их через главную ноду, то они будут вызваны как `$Golova` и `$Player/Golova`
3. Ваша нода находится на другой сцене

[image: Дерево сцен]

(Ошибка `Invalid get index 'position' (on base: 'null instance')` вызвана ошибкой ненахождения ноды и пропадет при её решении)

P.s: Если что-то не понятно или решение проблемы не удалось, свяжитесь со мной через [telegram](https://web.telegram.org/k/#@Xukku), для более удобного взаимодействия

Comment: К сожалению это не сработало. С нодами у меня вроде всё нормально. На главной сцене игрок сам, и к нему привязана голова, и выводит ошибку:
E 0:00:00.927   get_node: (Node not found: "Golova" (relative to "/root/Game/Sprite/Golova").)
  <Ошибка C++>  Method failed. Returning: nullptr
  <Исходный код C++>scene/main/node.cpp:1476 @ get_node()
  <Трассировка стека>Golova.gd:3 @ _ready()
И ещё то что ей не нравиться что то с position:
Invalid get index 'position' (on base: 'null instance').